# Smallest required change to elect Thomas Dewey as POTUS in 1948?

Tags: government, politics, history

As the question says, let's hear your ideas for how this famous headline printed in error could have been made a political reality...

[image]

Bonus points if your history changes begin after the end of WWII (either theater).

Comment: Voting to close as story-based; that is, you are asking about a plot point in your story, not about the world in which the story is set. Anyway, as you already know, Truman was not expected to win. So make Dewey put some credible effort in his campaign, and have Strom Thurmond better at explaining why electing Truman would be a disaster for the Democratic Party. Or have Truman lose the Democratic Party nomination. You may even consider the possibility for Eisenhower to accept the Democratic Party nomination.

Comment: If you can find it, I highly recommend the book The Glory and the Dream. It has a super detailed description of the race and why it came out the way it did.

Answer (score 1):

Truman dies a week before the election date. It’s a very small change, and the ensuing confusion would probably tip the balance in what was a fairly close election.

Comment: AFAIK under those conditions his party would have selected another candidate, most likely the vice presidential candidate or the convention runner-up.  It's not at all clear that this would definitely favored Dewey.  The vice-presidential candidate would have already been a recognized campaign figure so he's the likeliest choice.  Under those conditions there's a sympathy vote sometimes, so this could have been worse for Dewey, not better - it's a no slam dunk to ensure his election.